# Cant remove white space on my wordpress

Tags: themes

site: www.etech.com.vu

I am almost at wits end trying to figure how to get rid of the whitespace on my home page between the carousel and the footer.

I'm using a theme (green lantern) and cant seem to find the html for the home page ( I can edit the other pages fine)

Would be very grateful if someone can point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you can hide the "blog" section of home page, yo can add this css code:

```
.section-content.section-alter{
display: none;
}
```